# sed/awk regular expression to remove first set of parentheses

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'm very new to Unix so please bear with me. I have hundreds of files in the following format, each with hundreds of rows although the 2 letters in brackets will vary by file:

```
(SC)-ID             VARCHAR2(10)
(SC)-POLICY-NO      VARCHAR2(20)
(SC)-NAME           VARCHAR2(50)
(SC)-CODE           VARCHAR2(2)
(SC)-TERM           VARCHAR2(20)
(SC)-VAR-CODE       VARCHAR2(5)
(SC)-CONTRACT-TYPE  VARCHAR2(5)
POSTCODE            VARCHAR2(20)
....
....
....
```

I need to be able to manipulate all those files so the first set of parentheses **only** are removed to result in:

```
SC-ID             VARCHAR2(10)
SC-POLICY-NO      VARCHAR2(20)
SC-NAME           VARCHAR2(50)
SC-CODE           VARCHAR2(2)
SC-TERM           VARCHAR2(20)
SC-VAR-CODE       VARCHAR2(5)
SC-CONTRACT-TYPE  VARCHAR2(5)
POSTCODE          VARCHAR2(20)
....
....
....
```

Using any kind of global substitution (understandably) results in *both* sets of parentheses being removed from both lines e.g.

```
sed 's/[()]//g'
awk -F" " '{gsub(/\(|\)/,"");print}'
```

But if I don't use a global substitution e.g.

```
sed 's/[()]//g'
awk -F" " '{sub(/\(|\)/,"");print}'
```

it just strips the **first** opening bracket from each line but only if it is of the format specified i.e. (alpha alpha)

Is there a way of incorporating a regular expression into what I'm looking to replace so only (alpha alpha) are replaced with alpha alpha and all other brackets are ignored? There isn't much point posting my efforts to incorporate any regex as they either stripped all alphabetical characters or are ignored completely.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are some great answers here thank you. However, having now looked at all the files in more detail I see there is the occasional row that does not follow the pattern I originally specified hence the solutions strip off brackets I need to retain. Please see the edited question. A million apologies. Thanks again.

Comment: This can be solved by testing if its starting with `(`, then remove it.  Or do you have other pitfalls? (see my updated answer)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your responses. You are an incredibly talented and helpful bunch of experts. The variety of answers shows there is more than one way to crack a nut in Unix! Wish I could vote up all your answers but don't have the reputation to do so. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the POSIX one-letter motifs, that will catch uppercase as well as lowercase characters, but not the digits. So my solution is simply:

```
sed 's/(\([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]\))/\1/g'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks jaybee. I really wanted to use [[:alpha:]] in there because I'm used to using the Regex character classes in PL/SQL but just couldn't get there. Much more reading on sed required for me I think. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your awk command is too close,

```
awk '{gsub(/\(|\)/,"",$1);print}' file
```

To get the output format as same as the input then fed the output of awk command to `column -t`,

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\(|\)/,"",$1)}1' file | column -t
SC-ID             VARCHAR2(10)
SC-POLICY-NO      VARCHAR2(20)
SC-NAME           VARCHAR2(50)
SC-CODE           VARCHAR2(2)
SC-TERM           VARCHAR2(20)
SC-VAR-CODE       VARCHAR2(5)
SC-CONTRACT-TYPE  VARCHAR2(5)
```

Another GNU sed trick,

```
$ sed -r 's/\)//1;s/\(//1' file
SC-ID             VARCHAR2(10)
SC-POLICY-NO      VARCHAR2(20)
SC-NAME           VARCHAR2(50)
SC-CODE           VARCHAR2(2)
SC-TERM           VARCHAR2(20)
SC-VAR-CODE       VARCHAR2(5)
SC-CONTRACT-TYPE  VARCHAR2(5)
```

The above sed command removes open  `)` and close `(` parenthesis in the first column only.

Comment: You can remove the `-F" "` since its default

Comment: And you can also remove the `print` and use `1`: `awk '{gsub(/\(|\)/,"",$1)}1'`

Comment: I does change the column width since you are changing one of the field `$1` and not the whole string `$0`. It then reconstruct the line with the default field separator.

Answer (score 0):

This sed can do the job:

```
sed -i.bak 's/(\([^)]*\))/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Some like this?

```
awk '/^\(/ {sub(/\(/,"");sub(/\)/,"")}1' file
SC-ID             VARCHAR2(10)
SC-POLICY-NO      VARCHAR2(20)
SC-NAME           VARCHAR2(50)
SC-CODE           VARCHAR2(2)
SC-TERM           VARCHAR2(20)
SC-VAR-CODE       VARCHAR2(5)
SC-CONTRACT-TYPE  VARCHAR2(5)
POSTCODE            VARCHAR2(20)
....
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
sed 's/^(\([A-Z][A-Z]\))/\1/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents for this simple:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/(//' -e 's/)//' file
```

Or as Jotne suggested, this cleaner:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/(//;s/)//' file
```

Comment: You can change this to `'s/(//;s/)//'`

Comment: Yep , is nicer. Thanks @Jotne !

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^\((.*?)\)(.*)/$1$2/g' your_file
```

Test:

```
> cat temp2
(SC)-ID             VARCHAR2(10)
(SC)-POLICY-NO      VARCHAR2(20)
(SC)-NAME           VARCHAR2(50)
(SC)-CODE           VARCHAR2(2)
(SC)-TERM           VARCHAR2(20)
(SC)-VAR-CODE       VARCHAR2(5)
(SC)-CONTRACT-TYPE  VARCHAR2(5)
POSTCODE            VARCHAR2(20)

> perl -pe 's/^\((.*?)\)(.*)/$1$2/g' temp2
SC-ID             VARCHAR2(10)
SC-POLICY-NO      VARCHAR2(20)
SC-NAME           VARCHAR2(50)
SC-CODE           VARCHAR2(2)
SC-TERM           VARCHAR2(20)
SC-VAR-CODE       VARCHAR2(5)
SC-CONTRACT-TYPE  VARCHAR2(5)
POSTCODE            VARCHAR2(20)
```